# Why isn't Java's ArrayList <Integer> get() returning the correct comparison for ==?

Tags: java, arraylist

I recently started learning about Java's `ArrayList` class, and I wrote a small piece of code to test some of the functionality out:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestProgram {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        ArrayList <Integer> l = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
        l.add(255);
        l.add(255);

        System.out.println(l.get(0) == l.get(1));
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, the output of this code segment is `false`. I don't know why this would be (because 255 = 255), so could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Because you are comparing Integer objects not primitives int

Comment: You cannot safely use `==` to compare Objects like String or Integer. That only works with primitives. Must use `equals` instead.

Comment: This is a common beginner error with regards to Java. On `l.get(0)`, you're not actually getting `255` but an `Integer` `Object`, and when you're doing the `==` comparison, you're comparing the pointers of the object, not the values. To really compare the values of the object you have to use comparison methods of the `Integer` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this instead:

```
System.out.println(l.get(0).equals(l.get(1)));
```

You are comparing Objects, instead of primitives.